# Call method from apex class in lighting component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have a lighting component and a controller. What is the easiest way to make a call to a method i have in one of my apex classes and then using the return value to update the current record with that value?

Comment: this question does not show much research effort, have you gone through the trailheads, or at least checked the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

The (one) way to perform an Aura server controller call is documented in the [Lightning Aura Components Developer Guide under "Calling a Server-Side Action"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm). I'll reproduce and abbreviate the skeleton of the sample code here:

```
    var action = cmp.get("c.serverEcho");
    action.setParams({ firstName : cmp.get("v.firstName") });


    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            // do something
        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            // do something
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Pretty much all Lightning server calls look like this unless you built handler methods to abstract it or wrapped it in a `Promise`.

If your client-side is holding state related to this record, you'd make `component.set()` calls in your `state === "SUCCESS"` branch to persist any changes you received from the server into your client attributes.